# GWT 2.7 Custom Compiler Run - Incremental Build Not Working

Tags: gwt, compilation

I am currently building a transparent GWT compiler that is meant to run the compile process every time a class of a module changes also I want to get rid of the GWT files.

Everything is working so far but I noticed the GWT Compiler is dead slow. It takes him 10 seconds to compile a single permutation of a single class just adding a button and a label to the rootpane.

So what am I missing for the incremental build feature to work. I already set the working directory to a location where it stores the permutation file.